# Execute SQL in postgres database from AWS Glue to insert a single record

Tags: python, postgresql, amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I need to insert a single row into a Postgres database from AWS glue, then periodically update it with statuses as it continues down the ETL pipeline. My Postgres instance is in a VPC which makes this all very challenging. Basically I want to run the code:

```
def slmFilesUpdate(**kwargs):
    try:
        print(args)
        config_port = 5432
        conn = pg8000.connect(
            database=args['dbname'], 
            user=args['user'], 
            password=args['password'],
            host=args['host'],
            port=config_port
        )
        if kwargs['Type'] == 'Insert':
            query = f"INSERT INTO slm_files VALUES ({kwargs['id']}, {kwargs['filename']}, {kwargs['status']}, {kwargs['upload_method']}, {kwargs['file_type']});"
            cur = conn.cursor()
            cur.execute(query)
            conn.commit()
            cur.close()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

    finally:
        if conn:
            conn.close()
```

in a glue job. is that even possible?